# How do I render column and table names to quoted strings in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a column name that needs to be quoted in SQL statements. So when I render a query using `str()` in sql alchemy, quotes appear around it.

Is there a way I can get a quoted version of **just** the name of the column?

When I do `str(column)`, I get `'<table>.<column>'` when what I want is `'<table>."<column>"'`. Or when I do `str(column.name)`, I get `'<column>'` when I want `'"<column>"'`.

FWIW, I'm using the raw connection in psycopg in order to execute a bulk load using the `COPY` command in postgres (`cursor.copy_from`) and the `copy_from` function requires fully quoted column names, which is why I need them.

Alternatively, some sort of `is_reserved(name)` function would suffice.

Browsing the docs have proved fruitless so far :(

I could technically rename the column, but I'd like to use that as a last resort.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Took a while to find it. Assuming `engine` is your `sqlalchemy.engine.Engine` object:

[`engine.dialect.identifier_preparer.quote(name)`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/internals.html?highlight=dialect#sqlalchemy.sql.compiler.IdentifierPreparer.quote)