# Escape dynamic camelCase fields in sqlalchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a query such as:

```
select_query = [text(f) for f in fields]
with engine.connect() as conn:
    query = select(*select_query, MyTable.id).select_from(
        table(MyTable.__tablename__) ...
```

Everything works fine except when the field (inside select_query) is camelcase. Is there any function or directive to pass sqlalchemy so the camelcase fields do not break the select ?

Comment: PostgreSQL will usually downcase field names automatically unless they are explicitly quoted, so `select nAmE from t` is the same as `select name from t`.  Are your column names in the database mixed-case?

Comment: Yes, this is the problem, i have a camelcase column name. I know this is bad pratcice, but this is what I'm trying to work around

Comment: By the way, by following this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41291548/how-do-i-render-column-and-table-names-to-quoted-strings-in-sqlalchemy
I tried to replace the select query declaration with
select_query = [text(engine.dialect.identifier_preparer.quote(f)) for f in fields]

But now it says the column does not exist (which is false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the behaviour that you want using the [column](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.column) construct (note the lower-case "c") rather than the text construct. Using `column` tells SQLAlchemy that it is dealing with a column name rather than some arbitrary SQL fragment, so it can assume that the name is correctly cased and quote accordingly.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
...
select_query = [sa.column(f) for f in fields] 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

@snakecharmerb's answer is correct, however I forgot to specify that my "fields" strings also contains the table ("table.myColumn"). So I had to do some lunatic scripting to fix my problem

```
    list_strings = [
        f.rsplit('.', 1)[0] + '.' + engine.dialect.identifier_preparer.quote(f.rsplit('.', 1)[1])
        for f in fields
    ]
    select_query: List[TextClause] = [text(f) for f in list_strings]
```

This works, however, I recommend to anyone who can to switch to snake case for db fields